# Use TypeScriptToLua with AzerothCore and Eluna Lua Engine

Tags: typescript, lua, azerothcore, eluna-lua-engine, typescript-to-lua

I would like to write [Eluna](http://www.elunaengine.com/) scripts using [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) instead of [Lua](https://www.lua.org/) for my [AzerothCore](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk) application (using the [AC Eluna module](https://github.com/azerothcore/mod-eluna-lua-engine)).

Is there an easy way to combine it with the [TypeScriptToLua](https://github.com/TypeScriptToLua/TypeScriptToLua) tool ? Ideally with automatic code watch and rebuild on changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a repository to use typescript to lua on azerothcore using eluna https://github.com/azerothcore/eluna-ts

Demo reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEmjdauPKH0